# Replace !x with x != 1

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

I have some logical relationships that I ultimately want to pass to `NMaximize` as constraints: `{x => a, y => a, a => x || y}`

`NMaximize` is picky about its input format though, so I'm feeding the expression into `BooleanMinimize` before, which produces something like: `{!x || a, !y || a, ...}`.

`NMaximize` can't handle unary negation, but accepts `x! = 1`. I looked at `BooleanConvert`, but most of the forms still use logical negation. What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: But `!x` is not the same as `x != 1`... consider what you get when `x = 1` (or anything, for that matter)

Comment: `!1     =   0,
!0     =   1,
1!=1   =   0,
0!=1   =   1`

under the additional constraints {0 <= x <= 1, x e Integers}

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. Please provide more contextual info about your problem.

Comment: `constraints = {x ⇒ y||z}`  
`converted   = constraints /. a_⇒b_ :> (a!= 1||b!=0)`  
`NMaximize[{x+y+z, converted}, {x,y}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you seek, but just in case the plain answer happens to be it:

```
{! x || a, ! y || a} /. Not[n_] :> n != 1
```

> ```
> {x != 1 || a, y != 1 || a}
> ```

Comment: `Not[]`?? 4 characters more than the obvious one, `! n_ :> n != 1`  ø_Ø? You need some sleep...

Comment: @rm-rf LOL -- yes; yes, I do.

Comment: Yea, this is pretty much what was needed - thanks. Replacing `!x` wasn't enough though. Even `x` in the positive form makes `NMaximize` cry. Doing `constraints /. a_⇒b_ :> (a!= 1||b!=0)` works fine though.

Comment: @rm-rf Still haven't slept yet but I'm back to mangle some more answers. :o)

Comment: @Neal I'm glad it worked out for you.